# Dependency isn't compiling with project (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've set the scope to compile and am using `mvn clean package` to compile the jar. The issue is the dependency that's set to compile isn't compiling in the jar. my pom is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.awstin</groupId>
    <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please expand on "the dependency that's set to compile isn't compiling in the jar" I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: the scope of the json is set to compile.. This is my first time using maven so I might be using the wrong terms.

Comment: What do you think `<scope>compile</scope>` does and why do you think so?

Comment: Someone told me a while ago that it compiles with the jar... is that not correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. Please read a basic maven tutorial, you are using it completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want your `org.json:json` inside your jar (?).

In that case, you can use `maven-shade-plugin` and specify which dependency you want in your jar (in your case `org.json:json`)

```
      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- relevant part-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.json:json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```